# How to query multiple columns using pandas multiIndex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index, querying

Do you know how to query multiple columns on the 2nd level (level = 1) for all indices in the 1st level (level = 0)?

For example:
How do I query Mustard and Ketchup for all burgers?

| burgers | double-double |  |  | triple |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| condiments | ketchup | mustard | relish | ketchup | mustard | relish |
| Beep's Burgers | 3 | 3 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| Roadhouse | 3 | 5 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 2 |

I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_level_values()` on the columns and apply your filter logic

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""burgers double-double           triple      
condiments  ketchup mustard relish  ketchup mustard relish
Beep's Burgers  3   3   3   4   5   5
Roadhouse   3   5   2   3   3   2
"""), sep="\t", header=None)

# reconstruct multi-index columns DF...
df1 = df.iloc[2:].rename(columns={0:"burgers"}).set_index("burgers")
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.iloc[0,1:].fillna(method="ffill").values, df.iloc[1,1:].values], names=df.iloc[0:2,0])

# get required columns based on condiment
df1.loc[:,df1.columns.get_level_values("condiments").isin(["ketchup","mustard"])]
```